# How can I insert math formulas into a Morea page?

Tags: morea-framework

I want to insert math formulas into a Readings page in Morea.  I have looked at the existing markdown syntax and it does not support mathematics. I would like to be able to use LaTeX math expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morea now has built-in support for MathJax:

http://morea-framework.github.io/userguide.html#Equationsupport